# Sample ribbon based interface similar to paint

Tags: xaml, ribbon

Is there some sample code for ribbon based interface similar to powerpoint as a simple authoring program that I want to practice writing code for ribbon based UIs. A simpler version of paint that ships with Windows 7 will also be very helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSDN has article about [Ribbon (WPF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff799534.aspx) and in downloads section you will find

> the assemblies
>   and license files that are required to
>   use the ribbon, and **project templates**
>   and designer support for Visual Studio
>   2010 and Expression Blend 4